Excel Count formula does not work between 2 OneDrive files
I’m working with two separate Excel files saved on Microsoft 365 OneDrive.
To simplify, let’s assume that in file A, I have a series of numeric values ranging from 0 to 5000 located in column V.
My goal is to count how many of these values are equal to 1000.
So, in file B, I use the following formula:
=COUNTIF('[<sharepoint_path>/A.xlsx]Sheet1'!$V:$V,"=1000")

The result of the formula is #VALUE!
I also tried changing the formula criterion to "="&"1000" or "="&1000, but the result remains the same.
Of course, the same formula works perfectly when used directly in file A.
Why is this error happening?

If the other workbook is closed it won't work.  Help on the function states:  This error occurs when the formula that contains the function refers to cells or a range in a closed workbook and the cells are calculated. For this feature to work, the other workbook must be open.

If the other workbook is open then just =COUNTIF('[A.xlsx]Sheet1'!$V:$V,1000) will work - no need for quotes or = sign in the criteria.

Thanks for the answer, but the files are both open (i'm working with the online version - don't know if change something)

The online version doesn't really treat the workbooks as being open in the same instance, so that won't work. You can use something like =SUM(IF('[<sharepoint_path>/A.xlsx]Sheet1'!$V:$V=1000,1,0)) but you would be better off  not using entire columns if you can avoid it.

@Rory i'tried your solution (with "COUNT"), but the results its the count of the entire column... seems like the =1000 it's always true for some reason.
And if i use V1:V999 the count it's 999

Use SUM not COUNT. It is adding 1 for each matching row, so it acts as a count.
